# Recursive Func call in Halide

Tags: c++, halide

I'm using Halide and trying to calculate the size of maximum connected cells for given 2-dimensional input. The idea is to use recursive function but I don't know how to write it in Halide language.

Refernece python script and expected results are as follows.

```
import random

N = 4
data = [[0 for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
for index in range(N*N):
    data[index/N][index%N] = (random.randint(0,100) & 1)

print "Input"   
for d in data:
    print d

def ret(x, y):
    if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= N or y >= N:
        return 0
    if data[y][x] == 0:
        return 0

    data[y][x] = 0

    return ret(x, y-1) + ret(x, y+1) + ret(x-1, y) + ret(x+1, y) + 1

result = [[0 for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]

for y in range(4):
    for x in range(4):
        result[y][x] = ret(x, y)

print "Output"  
for r in result:
    print r


"""
Input
[1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1]
Output
[1, 0, 6, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 0]
"""
```

Halide implementation is here, but I've got the error message below.

```
#include "Halide.h"
using namespace Halide;

#define N 6

int main() {

    Image<uint8_t> input(N, N);
    for(int y = 0; y < N; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
                    input(x, y) = rand() & 1;
                    printf("%3d", input(x, y));
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    Var x("x"), y("y");

    Func input_f("input_f"), f("f");
    input_f(x, y) = input(x, y);

    f(x, y) = BoundaryConditions::constant_exterior(input_f, 0, 0, N, 0, N)(x, y);
    f(x, y) = select(f(x, y) != 0, f(x-1, y) + f(x+1, y) + f(x, y-1) + f(x, y+1) + 1, 0);

    Image<uint8_t> output = f.realize(N, N);
    for(int y = 0; y < N; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
                    printf("%3d", output(x, y));
            }
            printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Error Message:

```
In definition of Func "f":
All of a functions recursive references to itself must contain the same pure variables in the same places as on the left-hand-side.
```

According to the error message, I cannot use 'x-1' and 'x+1' in the right-hand-side. But I want to do so.
Is there any way to realize such a recursive Func call?

*I don't stick to recursive call if I could get expected result in Halide.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write recursive calls in Halide. Perhaps try Tiramisu.
http://tiramisu-compiler.org/